# Pyinstaller debugging log for application using Tkinter, Tensorflow

Tags: python, tkinter, pyinstaller

When trying to convert my python file to an .exe using pyinstaller, the .exe file is created but crashes on launch. Fatal error: failed to execute script predictor.py. This script uses Tkinter and Tensorflow.

Here is the terminal command

```
pyinstaller --onefile --hidden-import tkinter --debug all --icon=predictor.ico predictor.py
```

And here is the debug log
https://hastebin.com/hawuzigevu.coffeescript

Is there any indication to why it crashes in the debug log?

Comment: the log did mention that it couldn't find sklearn.

Comment: you actually dont have to hidden import tkinter if you are importing it in your code. This error might be becuase `sklearn` not there in your interpretter installed? are you using an env?

Answer (score 0):

on line 382:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn'`

it seems you're missing a module.

Furthermore, this is a matter of personal taste, when trying to compile Tkinter scripts to executables, you could try [auto-py-to-exe](https://pypi.org/project/auto-py-to-exe/) instead of pyinstaller.